# Low cost 30A 24Vto12V stepdown converter

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, buck, step-down

I'm trying to design a 24V to 12V step down converter. Power efficiency is not that important to me, but I want to come up with the cheapest solution possible. I don't need isolation neither. So I though I would just come up with the simplest buck converter. Something like this

[image]

Sw2 would of course be an appropriate power MOSFET. Also the schottky diode is arbitrary, just used the first thing available in Circuit Lab.

Would such a simple buck converter be the cheapest solution for my application, and would it work, assuming that ripple is not a concern for my application?

EDIT: Second part of the question was if it works with such a simple feedback loop. There is a similar question which is already answered so I removed that part.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your current requirement? Is it really 30A?

Comment: Yep. 30A peak. Say 15-20A continuous.

Comment: Is the load really similar to a resistor? It is actually possible to run a buck converter without feedback if the load is invariable. In your case, something a little over 50% duty cycle would do it. If you want precisely regulated output voltage, then of course you need feedback of some sort.

Comment: @mkeith No, the resistor is just for simulation. The load is variable and can be anything.

Comment: @Olinlathrop I edited the question and edited the duplicate question out

Comment: The duplicate post, and another one linked to from inside that post provide a lot of information on hysteretic buck regulation. Definitely worth reading.

Comment: I hope your not going to use a relay with this application, they won't switch fast enough

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not 100% sure on cost, a buck converter would very likely be the *best* solution for your problem.

As for your circuit working, it would work right up until your Vout reached 12V; then the MOSFET switch should open, but all the stored energy in the inductor would continue charging the capacitor to some overvoltage level determined by inductor/capacitor size ratios (and instantaneous load).

Now, with a sufficiently small inductor value, a small shunt resistor and sufficiently high capacitor value, that could end up being a small enough difference to not matter. Depending, of course, on what error factor you're willing to accept in your 12VDC output.

For a better solution than trying to brute-force your circuit with a self-oscillating converter, the [TL494](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TL494CNSR/296-10191-1-ND/380460) controller looks like it'd work well for you (using appropriately high-power MOSFET(s) for the switching, of course), and it's incredibly inexpensive. :)

A read-through of the datasheet for that controller should tell you what you'll need for how to set up your converter based around it.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer something like an synchronous buck controller. You can connect external FETs, (n channel) and the current is mainly Independent from your controller. You need something like a charge pump or bootstrap circuit to drive the high switch. I would prefer a synchronous solution, because 20A over the power diode are about 20W.
With a Low Side mosfet, power dissapation of the switch can be in the range of one to two watts.